# не ставится Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Копирую файл установки bitrixsetup.php на сервер, перехожу по ссылке site.ru/bitrixsetup.php и получаю вот такое: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя файлы php на сервере исполняются!

Comment: Safe Mode в настройках php отключите и права на папки проверяйте.

Comment: @Andrew Hobbit проверил все нормально там

Comment: короткие тэги попробуйте включить

Comment: короткие теги не помогли

Comment: Если посмотреть в инспекторе кода, то получается что он весь php код ставит закомментированным

Comment: это похоже на ввыключеные короткие теги

Comment: @alexandrovdi расскажите, _как именно_ вы включали короткие теги?
Предъявите ваш `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 1):

PHP точно выполняется через браузер?
Если да, скачайте скрипт проверки сервера на требования битрикс [bitrix_server_test.php](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/download/scripts/bitrix_server_test.php) запустите через браузер и покажите, что он выводит

Вот здесь можно почитать про скрипт https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=32&LESSON_ID=3262